# iTunes won't open

Tags: macos, itunes

Running El Capitan on a Mac Mini and latest version of iTunes (as of 21st Oct 2016).  When I click iTunes icon it just "bounces" in the system tray.  Eventually stops bouncing but iTunes does not open.

The Mac OSX Activity Monitor says the iTunes process is not running.  No errors occur.

Have tried opening the system log while opening iTunes but no errors are reported.

Can only be fixed by restarting the Mac.  This would be fine but my Mac Mini is my media server, so is a real pain to keep rebooting.

Comment: Also, quite often the Mac just refused to restart at all and I have to pull the plug.  I wait a good 5-10 minutes too - so its not me being impatient.

Comment: Did you try looking at the Console to see what happened?

Comment: Yes, as I said above, if I open the system log (console) while iTunes is trying to open then nothing is logged

Comment: I have the same issue